# adjust recursive sql query to exclude holidays and weekends

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, recursive-query

I have a dataset like this called data_per_day

| instructional_day | points |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-01-24 | 2 |
| 2023-01-23 | 2 |
| 2023-01-20 | 1 |
| 2023-01-19 | 0 |

and so on. the table shows weekdays (days minus holidays and weekends) and the number of points someone has earned. 1 is the start of a  streak and 0 is the end of a streak. 2 is max points after a streak has started.

I need to find how long is the latest streak. so in this case the result should be 3

I created a recursive cte but the query returns 2 as the streak count because i'm using lag mechanism with days. instead I need to adjust so that the instructional days are used rather than all dates.

```
  RECURSIVE cte AS (
  SELECT
    student_unique_id,
    instructional_day,
    points,
    1 AS cnt
  FROM
    `data_per_day`
  WHERE
    instructional_day = DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE('America/Chicago'), INTERVAL -1 DAY)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    a.student_unique_id,
    a.instructional_day,
    a.points,
    c.cnt+1
  FROM (
    SELECT
      *
    FROM
      `data_per_day`
    WHERE
      points > 0 ) a
  INNER JOIN
    cte c
  ON
    a.student_unique_id = c.student_unique_id
    AND a.instructional_day = c.instructional_day - INTERVAL '1' day )
SELECT
  student_unique_id,
  MAX(cnt) AS streak
FROM
  cte --
WHERE
  student_unique_id = "419"
GROUP BY
  student_unique_id
```

How do I adjust the query?

Comment: Can you provide a bigger input table and the expected output?

Comment: The result should be 3 because there are 3 consecutive records with positive points, omitting weekends and holidays?  (1/20, 1/23, 1/24)

Comment: Dates are handled different in each RDBMS.  Which one are you using?

Comment: @dougp i'm using bigquery

Answer (score 0):

This is not a trivial coding exercise, so I won't actually write the code and provide it.

What you have here is a [gaps and islands](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22gaps%20and%20islands%22) question.  You want to identify the largest "island" of days with points within a date range.  Depending upon what dates are contained in your data, you may need to generate a list of sequential dates that meet your criteria.

One problem I see is that you are trying to combine the steps to generate the date range (the recursive CTE) with the points.  You'll need to separate those steps.

1. Define the date range.
2. Generate the dates within the range.
3. Filter the dates with `isweekday = 'no' and isholiday = 'no'`.  You will probably want to add a row number during this step.
4. [left] join the dates to your data, including `coalesce(points, 0)`
5. Filter the data to `points > 0`.
6. Identify the islands.
7. Identify the largest island per student.